# How to resize webview based on content?

Tags: google-chrome, chromium, electron

How can I embed content on my page, using the [`<webview />` element](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/tags/webview), in a way that allows the webview element to adapt its size based on the content within? Ideally, I would like to avoid scrollbars on the webview element and have the host page scrollbars work as if the content within the webview were part of the host page.

I'd like to support both short and long content within the webview similar to:

[image: Webview with short content]
[image: Webview with long content]

My page has some navigation elements at the top, which are not part of webview content.

For example, my page markup looks like the following:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div class="content-wrapper">
      <h1>My Page Title</h1>
      <nav class="main-navbar">
        <ul class="nav">
          <li><a href="#Home">Home</a></li>
          ...
        </ul>
      </nav>
      <webview src="..."></webview>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you developing the contents of the webview? I am thinking it would be possible to pass the size to the host via an ipc message... but I suppose that depends on whether or not you have control over what is in the webview.

Comment: @ShawnRakowski, yep, I'm controlling the content of the webview